# How to add new item dynamically with Select2 when No matches found?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I'm using select-2 with my Rails app to autocomplete a field with Ajax calls and allow multiple values.

My CoffeScript file :

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.select2').each (i, e) =>
    select = $(e)
    options =
      placeholder: select.data('placeholder')
      multiple: true
      width: "100%"      
      maximumSelectionSize: 20
      tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
      dropdownClass: 'bigdrop'      

    if select.hasClass('ajax')
      options.ajax =
        url: select.data('source')
        dataType: 'json'
        data: (term, page) ->
          q: term
          page: page
          per: 25
        results: (data, page) ->
          results: data.resources
          more: data.total > (page * 25) 

      options.dropdownCssClass = "bigdrop"

    select.select2(options)
```

I want to be able to add new item in case there were no results from the server, At the moment it wont allow me to add new item (not saved at the server and populated through Ajax calls).

Answer (score 0):

I had to use createSearchChoice something like the following:

```
  createSearchChoice: (term, data) ->
    if $(data).filter(->
      this.text.localeCompare(term) is 0
    ).length is 0
      id: term
      text: term
```